# JavaScript: Using 'contains' via underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My HTML:

```
<div class="info">...</div>
```

And I want, when I start my div with `'...'` make to `'display: none'`

For that, I try this via jQuery but not working:

```
    $(".info:contains('...')").css("display", "none");
```

Because my JavaScript file using underscore.js

Well, how can I display to none this div via underscore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
$(".info:contains('...')").hide();
```

Please let me know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

underscore.js is an Javascript utility library and not meant for DOM manipulation.
I tested your code and its working fine. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amitesh_Bharat/tnes9nwa/) containing both Jquery and underscore library.

```
No dot <div class="info">...</div>

$(".info:contains('...')").css("display", "none");
```